# Why are my "nav" align and background color not working?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 CSS stylings for my nav for a background and to align the nav items to center of the navigation bar; however, for whatever reason the alignment and background color only show when I remove the closing brace for the "nav" CSS.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding: .25em 4em 0em 1em;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  transition: background-color .25s linear, color .25s linear;
}

.navbar .current {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  color: #ff2c7b;
  position: relative;
}

.current::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="current" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
  <a href="teamreports.html">Team Reports</a>
  <a href="#">Team Compendium</a>
  <a href="#">Resources</a>
  <a href="#">Events</a>
</nav>
<br />
<div>
  <p>Sample text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

I'm still currently learning HTML and CSS, but I figured trying to recreate websites as close as I could would help me learn the skills to then create my own.

Comment: Can you explain better you desired result?

Comment: So, I'm wanting the entire navigation bar to have a background color of gray prior to the CSS styling of the hover and the active. Also, I'm wanting my nav options to be centered within the full navigation bar. Currently it's defaulted to the left-align.

Answer (score 1):

Your `nav` element contains floated elements which by default will not be included in the parent's space on the page automatically, i.e. `nav` will vertically not be extended to cover them and therefore will have a height of 0 because it only contains floated elements. To avoid that, add `overflow: auto;` to `nav` .

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding: .25em 4em 0em 1em;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  transition: background-color .25s linear, color .25s linear;
}

.navbar .current {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  color: #ff2c7b;
  position: relative;
}

.current::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="current" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
  <a href="teamreports.html">Team Reports</a>
  <a href="#">Team Compendium</a>
  <a href="#">Resources</a>
  <a href="#">Events</a>
</nav>
<br />
<div>
  <p>Sample text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your `nav` rules :

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Add an _explanation_ as to why that is necessary to your answer ;-)